# Do American people pronounce "mutter" like "mudder"?

Tags: listening

I heard "muttering" when I was practicing my listening.

I couldn't figure it out even I knew the meaning in the sentence. It sounded like "muddering". I searched "muder" in search engine, it gave me "murder". Finally, I gave it up, then watched the answer, it was a "muttering".

When I hear a word which I don't know, How do I find it out?

Comment: Can you add the entire sentence using the word? Since you knew what the sentence meant, there might be some clue other than what it sounded like.

Comment: Also see the earlier *[Pronounce double t in AmE](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/129167)* and the related *[Americans flap the /d/ of the consonant cluster /rd / if it is between two vowels, right?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155311)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called [flapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping), and yes it does make both ["mutter"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mutter) and ["mudder"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/mudder) sound exactly the same (both are /ˈmədər/). Flapping is done in American English and some other dialects of English.

In order to figure out what word you're hearing, context is vital, as is knowing a couple of likely candidate spellings:

- The search engine, in some cases, will know what you're trying to type if you search with context. For example, Google suggests the right spelling if I search for "muddering under your breath" or even "muering under your breath".
- In this case, you found one word it could be ("mudder", which is a very uncommon word), but you didn't find "mutter" because you didn't spell it with two t's (a single t is not right because it would be pronounced differently). It might be worth finding a dictionary that supports advanced search (I like [this site](http://www.puzzlers.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=solving:wordlists:dictionary_search), which uses regex syntax). A dictionary will help you know if the word fits or not in the sentence.
- Lastly, familiarity with the language always helps. The more you hear and read English, the more words you'll know.

You may also find [this answer of mine](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/129420/41273) helpful, since I explain more about flapping in general there.